# Prove that if A is singular, then adj(A) is also singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if A is singular, then adj(A) is also singular.
How do you prove this without proving by contradiction?

Comment: what do you mean by 'directly'?

Comment: $A \cdot adj(A)=D(\det(A))$ where $D$ means the diagonal matrix with all entries $\det(A).$

Comment: You can prove directly that $\mathrm{adj}(A)=0$ if $A$'s rank is at most $n-2$ ($n$ is the size of the square matrix $A$), and $\mathrm{rk}(\mathrm{adj}(A))=0$ if $\mathrm{rk}(A)=n-1$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Isn't $\operatorname{rk}(\operatorname{adj}(A))=1$ if  $\operatorname{rk}(A)=n-1$?

Comment: @user2097 Yes ^ ^, copy and paste at work.

Comment: The claim is only true when $A$ is an $n \times n$-matrix with $n \geq 2$. Do you see how it fails for $n = 1$ ?

Answer (score 4):

We know that $A\;adj(A)=det(A)\;I=diag(det(A))$. Since $A$ is singular, we have $det(A)=0$, which implies that $A\; adj(A)=0$.

- If $A=0$ (null and singular), then $adj(A)=0$ and hence $adj(A)$ is
  singular too.
- If $A\neq 0$ (nonnull and singular), then $A$ contains a nonnull row,
  say the $i$th row $a'_i$. It follows that $$a'_i\; adj(A)=0$$ which
  implies that the rows of $adj(A)$ are linearly dependent, and hence
  $adj(A)$ is singular.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the adugate matrix. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then if $A$ is singular 
$$
\operatorname{adj}A A=\det A1_{n\times n} = 0.
$$
There are two cases, if $\operatorname{rank}A=0$ the assertion is trivial. If $\operatorname{rank}A\neq0$ then $\operatorname{null}\operatorname{adj}A>0$, so it can't be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

From the basic equation: $A\,\text{adj}(A)=\det(A)I$ we have:
$$
\det(A\,\text{adj}A)=\det(\det(A)I)\\
\det(A)\det(\text{adj}(A))=\det(A)^n \det(I)
$$
$\det(\text{adj}(A))=\det(A)^{n-1}$

Since $A$ is singular,
$$
\det(\text{adj}(A))=0 
$$
and then $\text{adj}(A)$ is also singular

Comment: This argument does not work as stated, since you are dividing by $\det A$ which, as you yourself admit, is $0$. It would work with some subtler tricks, though.

Comment: Truth is i didn't see that. Seems you are correct and the answer is wrong.